# Why should I provide two different paths when creating alias?

Tags: bash, alias

When I issue `alias --help` I get this output:

```
alias: usage: alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]
```

As I understand, all you need to do is to type an alias and provide the actual path to the script file, like this:

```
alias scr = /usr/local/tools/some_script.sh
```

However, I noticed that sometimes 2 paths are being provided when creating aliases - for example, I issued `alias scr` command on a corporate machine and got this output:

```
alias scr = 'sudo /bin/sh /usr/local/tools/some_script.sh'
```

What is the purpose of introducing additional path `/bin/sh` in this case?

The /bin/sh contains only a symlink to bash directory:

```
ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug  6  2017 /bin/sh -> bash
```

Comment: An alias replaces one *string* with another *string* before the command is interpreted further. It's purely textual. The replacement string can even include `|`, `;` or `#`. Your question might be "why `/bin/sh /usr/local/tools/some_script.sh` and not just `/usr/local/tools/some_script.sh`?" The fact these strings may come from an alias is irrelevant. Don't think of an alias as of providing one or more paths. It provides a string. Upon *further* interpretation some substrings may turn out to be command(s) with options and/or (option-)arguments, possibly in form of paths.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor calm down, maggot

Comment: You say "and got this output" -- No you did not. Did you re-type it with the extra spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alias defined through

```
alias scr='sudo /bin/sh /usr/local/tools/some_script.sh'
```

(having spaces around the `=` is an error), calls `sudo` which in turn runs the script `/usr/local/tools/some_script.sh` by explicitly calling the `/bin/sh` shell interpreter with the script's pathname as an argument.

The `/bin/sh` is the pathname of the `sh` executable under `/bin` (in your case it's a symbolic link to `bash`, but that's unimportant).  It is used to run `sh` shell scripts.  In this case, the script at `/usr/local/tools/some_script.sh` is presumably a script written for `sh`, so the alias makes sure that it's called with `/bin/sh` as the interpreter.

If the script is executable and has a `#!`-line that points to a valid script interpreter as its first line, the `/bin/sh` bit can be removed.

So, in short, the alias allows you to run the command

```
/bin/sh /usr/local/tools/some_script.sh
```

as root by just typing `scr`.